# Vuejs undefined object inside a watched property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am having an issue with watched property in Vuejs. The error i am getting - `Cannot read property 'list' of undefined` even though the list **is** defined.
I am getting the error after it does the if check (at the `var index ....` line).

```
watch: {
   selectedRole: () => {
     if (this.modifiedUser.list) {
        var index = this.modifiedUser.list.findIndex(obj => obj.id == 
               this.selectedObj);
        this.modifiedUser.list[index].object = Object.assign({}, this.selectedObj);
  }
}
```

Any idea why it passes the check in the if statement but fails on the next line?

VueJs - v2.5.2.

Comment: The error doesn't mean `list` is undefined but `modifiedUser` is.

Comment: Can you try `if (this.modifiedUser && this.modifiedUser.list)` as your condition?

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer I did, now it still get into the if statement but the `var index` variable is undefined.

Comment: take the `var index` out of the if statement, and give it a default value above it. Then update it in the if statement, if the if-statement is true

Answer (score 0):

In `if (this.modifiedUser.list) {` try check if modifiedUser is undefined, please.

Check also if index isn't undefined after:

var index = this.modifiedUser.list.findIndex(obj => obj.id == 
               this.selectedObj);

Hope this helps

Comment: The modified user is defined, but the check fails.